# Interpret the Conditional Sigma (vs Realized Absolute Returns) of the DCC model

Tags: time-series, interpretation, garch

[image]

I have estimated a DCC model and now I have plot the `dcc.fit` of the model and now I would like to know if someone can help me to interpret this graph as I am new to this field, and I do not know what interpretation to do. Thanks!

Comment: Are these the fitted standard deviations of the four time series? In such case the fact that you run DCC is irrelevant, as you are interpreting the results of the *univariate* models fit for each time series separately. Meanwhile, DCC is (essentially) a model of the dependence *between* them, building on top of the univariate models. What univariate models did you specify? GARCH(1,1)?

Comment: Yes I have used a Garch(1,1) model to estimate the DCC model. I have used this  command                                                                                              
plot(dcc.fit) which the second plot gives me this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These seem to be the fitted conditional standard deviations (or perhaps variances) of four time series. On average, you would expect higher absolute returns when the distribution has a higher standard deviation (variance). This need not hold for every instance, only on average.

Whether this is what you see in the graphs is hard to tell, as there are so many data points squeezed in a small area. If you zoom in and find this to be the case, then there is nothing to worry about; the model implications do not contradict the data. If the high conditional standard deviations tend to occur where low absolute returns are observed, on average, that would be a cause for concern, as the model would be contradicting the data.

The fact that you run DCC is irrelevant here, as you are interpreting the results of the univariate models fit for each time series separately. Meanwhile, DCC is (essentially) a model of the dependence between them, building on top of the univariate models.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user366566, you are welcome!